# Windows Batch File - Multiple Conditions and Lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

I need to extract information from a file using BATCH file. I have AWK (GNUWIN32) installed in Windows.

Text File contains -

```
# FOR Example Purposes  *** #
# Dated on Jan 29, 2014

TEST_tag=branch_release_v_2.0.82.91_YOU_Branch
NONE_tag=branch_release_v_12.0.82.1_ONE_Branch
DOIT_tag=branch_release_v_1.0.9_EXA_Branch
```

Now, I need the following output from this file (comments removed and string manipulated)-

```
TEST/branch_release_v_2.0.82.91_YOU_Branch
NONE/branch_release_v_12.0.82.1_ONE_Branch
DOIT/branch_release_v_1.0.9_EXA_Branch
```

I will prefer if it can be done using variables instead of replacing "_tag=" with "/" so, I can use the logic with other formats as well.

Here what I tried to do.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('awk "!/^($|#)/" test.txt') DO (
ECHO %%A | awk -F_ "{print $1}" > one.tmp
SET /P ONE=<one.tmp

ECHO %%A | awk -F= "{print $2}" > two.tmp
SET /P TWO=<two.tmp

ECHO %ONE%/%TWO%
)
```

It's not working and is printing the same result (last line only printed 3 times)

```
DOIT/branch_release_v_1.0.9_EXA_Branch
DOIT/branch_release_v_1.0.9_EXA_Branch
DOIT/branch_release_v_1.0.9_EXA_Branch
```

**Solution (Thanks to Magoo) ---**

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('awk "!/^($|#)/" test.txt') DO (

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

ECHO %%A | awk -F_ "{print $1}" > one.tmp
SET /P ONE=<one.tmp

ECHO %%A | awk -F= "{print $2}" > two.tmp
SET /P TWO=<two.tmp

ECHO !ONE!/!TWO!
)
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.